# How to ignore Input while Javascript generates String

Tags: javascript

How do I ignore an Input in a Textarea while Javascript Generates Code.

I have the Script, that if the User presses Enter a Bulletpoint with a Space afterwards will be created on the new Line.

Now if I "spam" Enter and immidiatly buttons the Javascript isn't fast enought to Generate the Bulletpoint and I end up with Stuff like:

jiwnefun - fiuwmf i Instead of

- iunfeunf
- ifef
- ifjeif

```
_prefixBulletPoints(){
        var textArea = document.querySelector('#tools');
        let keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

        if(keycode === 13){
            textArea.value +='• ';
        }
        
        if(textArea.value.substr(textArea.value.length - 1 ) === '\n'){
            textArea.value = textArea.value.substring(0,textArea.value.length - 1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best way, but you can rebuild the text each time a newline is entered.

```js
function _prefixBulletPoints(event) {
  var textArea = document.querySelector('#tools');
  let keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

  if (keycode === 13) {
    // Delete all bullets
    textArea.value = textArea.value.replace(/• /g, "");
    // Add bullets back in the correct places
    textArea.value = "• " + textArea.value.replace(/\n/g, "\n• ");
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="tools" onkeyup="_prefixBulletPoints(event)">• </textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make input field disabled/readOnly  untill function  is complete

make input readonly in begining of function and remove readonly at end.

```
document.querySelector("#tools").readOnly = true;    
document.querySelector("#tools").readOnly = false;
```